# macOS: Looking for app to find duplicate files between 2 folders, 1st folder set to read-only, mutual duplicates only marked in 2nd folder

Tags: macos, comparison, duplicate-files, directories

I'm looking for a mac equivalent of MindGems Fast Duplicate File Finder on Windows. No affiliation.

As the feature list shows https://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-Features.htm , being able to treat one folder as read-only to have mutual duplicates marked only in the other non read-only folders is the crucial feature I need. In FDFF this feature is covered by 2 features:

- "Disable folders for self-scan (compare folders)" - which means that the duplicate search will not be done within that folder - the folder that is designated as "read-only".
- "Exclude folders from auto-check". This means that nothing is changed or removed in the folder designated as read-only. The read-only folder is still compared with the other folders to find duplicates, but that the duplicates found on both sides are always marked on the other folders only.

I've looked at various comparison list articles from not-really-established/biased product vendors websites and they all harp on about how they are the best, but they really dumb down and are superficial about their actual features. Which is a shame because then the user has to download and trial each one to discover what they might be able to do.

I want one of the directories to be ready only because it is a master archive and I don't want any files to be marked as duplicate and then to eb removed within it. I want it to be used as an absolute reference for comparing in other folders but not to have its own files deleted in the removal process.

I also use cross-platform Beyond Compare (BC) heavily across all platforms, it's brilliant in a several duplicate finding situations, but by default this does not compare files with different names. BC does provide for regex to match file names partially but one would have to make assumptions about how the file name could be different in order to formulate